# Removing JButton's text after it is clicked

Tags: java

For a game I'm making, I want the player to have a choice of two (or more) buttons, and when a button is clicked, a new screen appears.

However, as of now, the  1st button's text still remains when it is clicked. I've tried setVisible(false) in the listener, and later setText(" "), but both only create errors. If anyone could give me any other advice, I'd greatly appreciate it. I have the entirety of my game's panel below for reference, though only the the  B1Listener should be relevant to the issue.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class Panel00 extends JPanel
{
  private BufferedImage myImage;
  private Graphics myBuffer;
  public Timer timer;
  public JButton button1;
  public JButton button2;
  public JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Good Choice!");
  public JLabel label2 = new JLabel("You're Fired!!");
  public int x = 10;        //CountDown from 100    
  public int delay = 1000;  //milliseconds
  boolean drawWorld = false;



  public Panel00()
  {

  myImage = new BufferedImage(1000, 1000, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
  myBuffer = myImage.getGraphics();




  setLayout(null);


  JButton button1 = new JButton();
  button1.setSize(300, 200);
  button1.setLocation(100,150);
  button1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 18));
  button1.setText("<html><center>"+"Until we are able to determine and understand this problem"+"<br>"+" and the dangerous threat it poses, our country cannot be the victims of horrendous attacks"+"<br>"+"by people that believe only in Jihad, and have no sense of reason or respect for human life"+"</center></html>");
  button1.addActionListener(new B1Listener());
  button1.setBorder(null);
  button1.setOpaque(false);
  button1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
  button1.setBorderPainted(false);
  add(button1);

  JButton button2 = new JButton();
  button2.setSize(300, 200);
  button2.setLocation(600,150);
  button2.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 18));
  button2.setText("<html><center>"+"If ISIS wants to fight, fine with us. "+"<br>"+"We have wanted that fight for a long time. There is no room in the world for ISIS any more."+"<br>"+"The Muslims or us,  one of us will have to go."+"</center></html>");
  button2.addActionListener(new B2Listener());
  button2.setBorder(null);
  button2.setOpaque(false);
  button2.setContentAreaFilled(false);
  button2.setBorderPainted(false);
  add(button2);

  ActionListener counter = 
     new ActionListener() 
     {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
        { 
           repaint();
           x--;
           if (x == 0)
           {
              timer.stop();  
           }
        }
     };
  timer = new Timer(delay, counter);
  timer.start();


  setFocusable(true);  
  }


  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
  {
     ImageIcon Nintendo = new ImageIcon("trumpT.jpg");

  g.drawImage(Nintendo.getImage(), 0, 0, 1000, 1000, null);

  ImageIcon N = new ImageIcon("trump speech.jpg");

  g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
  g.fillOval(90,100,320,320);

  g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
  g.fillOval(590,100,320,320);

  g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
  g.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD, 50));
  g.drawString(""+x,500,50);

  if (drawWorld)
  {
     g.drawImage(N.getImage(), 0, 0, 1000, 1000, null); 
  }
 }

  private class B1Listener implements ActionListener
  {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
     repaint();
     drawWorld = true;

     label1.setLocation(500,700);
     label1.setSize(400, 400);
     label1.setForeground(new Color(212, 175, 55));
     label1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 40));
     add(label1);

     button1.setText("");

     timer.stop();

  }
}

  private class B2Listener implements ActionListener
  {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
     label2.setLocation(500,700);
     label2.setSize(400, 400);
     label2.setForeground(Color.RED);
     label2.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 40));
     add(label2);
     timer.stop();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: What kind of errors does it give you?

Comment: You need to set the event listeners in the same scope after declaring the buttons. To do so you can use the anonymous inner classes as suggested by @ControlAltDel

Answer (score 0):

Better to use an anonymous inner class, like

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    button1.setText("");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Panel00 constructor creates a local button1 that hides the instance variable button1, which remains null. And you are doing the same thing with button2.

in your constructor, change

```
 JButton button1 = new JButton();
  ...
 JButton button2 = new JButton();
```

to

```
  button1 = new JButton();
  ...
  button2 = new JButton();
```